# Toggle visibility of MVT features in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

Following code add layer with MVT features:

```
class Mvt {
    constructor() {
        this.format = new MVT({
            idProperty: 'id',
            geometryName: 'geom',
            featureClass: Feature,
        }),
        this.source = new VectorTileSource({
            url: 'http://{a-d}.myhost/mvt/{z}/{x}/{y}',
            format: this.format,      
            tileGrid: new TileGrid({...}),
        })
        this.layer = new VectorTileLayer({
            declutter: true,
            source: this.source,
            style: feature => someStyleFunction(feature)
        })
    }
}

const mvt = new Mvt()
map.addLayer(mvt.layer)
```

Each feature has `layer` attribute with correspond layer name, 
so it's possible to set layer list for reading of features by specifying that list in `format` property (or using `setLayers` method) as mentioned [here](https://openlayers.org/en/v6.1.1/apidoc/module-ol_format_MVT-MVT.html)

Knowing about this, it's tempting to implement toggling visibility of "layers" where "layer" is collection of features with the same `layer` attribute.

I've tried `mvt.format.setLayers([...])`, but changes take effect after subsequent request only(i.e zoom/pan interaction).

It would be perfect to redraw the tiles immediately or to refresh source of layer at least.

Does anyone know a trick to do it?

Comment: Have you tried calling `source.refresh()` after `.setLayers` ?

Comment: Yes,  `.refresh` works as expected, it's not bad.
It would be cool If only there was a way to avoid reload data from backend.